# .Net Decompiler and Editor for Linux

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I am looking for an application like dnSpy but for linux, I need to be able to edit the
code of the binary and also search for methods.

Comment: try 'ILSpy` for sth working on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't know why I didn't try this but for anyone searching for a decompiler, you can just run dnSpy with wine and it works perfectly at least for me on a debian based distro.